# python celery Workers appear to be spawning extra processes

Tags: python, celery

I have python celery project running, following the documentation here : http://celery.readthedocs.org/

LAYOUT:

```
celery_folder/celeryServer.py       # server to handle http requests
celery_folder/celeryconfig.py       # config file
celery_folder/start-celery.sh       # shell script to start the workers

celery_folder/myCelery/celery.py    # the celery app
celery_folder/myCelery/tasks.py     # function definitions
```

I can start the celery worker using the usual commands:

```
celery worker --app=<APP> --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
```

When I do this I get 2 new processes spawned that look like this in htop:

```
-bash
  -->/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker --app=myCelery --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
      -->/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker --app=myCelery --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
```

HOWEVER

when I add in the config file (`--config=celeryconfig.py`) then I get 4 processes spawned, like this:

```
--bash
  -->/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker --app=myCelery --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
      -->/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker --app=myCelery --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
          -->/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker --app=myCelery --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
      -->/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/celery worker --app=myCelery --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info --queues=remote
```

Why am I getting these extra processes. What are they doing?

Here's the config file:

```
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES  = 3600
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND       = 'amqp'
CELERY_CONCURRENCY          = 1
CELERY_ROUTES               = {'myCelery.tasks.home_task':{'queue':'remote'}}
CELERYD_AUTOSCALER          = 'celery.worker.autoscale:Autoscaler'
CELERY_IMPORT               = ('celery.task.http')
CELERY_INCLUDE              = 'myCelery.tasks'
```

EDIT : Here are celery.py and tasks.py

## projectFolder/myCelery/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

## projct/myCelery/tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from myCelery.celery import app

import os
import json
import requests
import datetime as dt
import dateutil.parser

from myCelery.<GITHUB REPO> import <FUNCTION FROM REPO>

def login():
    <CUSTOM FUNCTION REDACTED>

def write_token_to_file(data, headers):
    <CUSTMO FUNCTION REDACTED>

def get_headers():
    <REDACTED>

@app.task
def add(imei):
    <REDACTED>       

@app.task
def remote_task(imei):
    <REDACTED>
```

Comment: 1) how much process cores does your machine have.
2) try to disable CELERYD_AUTOSCALER option

Comment: single core only. It's an amazon ec2 instance.

Comment: follwoing your thought though, it's the line: 

`CELERY_INCLUDE              = 'myCelery.tasks'`

that causes the multiple processes to start, with that line commented out, only the process I want gets spawned.

Comment: ...but clearly the problem still stands since I want to be able in to include tasks.py etc...

Comment: is `tasks.py` just defining tasks or is it doing something that could be spawning more processes?

Comment: I've added `tasks.py` the only thing I can think is that `from myCelery.celery import app` is spawning the extra processes but I can't see what it would do such a thing..

Answer (score 1):

Two processes is pretty normal since celery uses a "main" process to talk to the 'pool' processses.

```
 celery -A python worker -c 1 -l debug
```

...

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ps aux | grep celery
vagrant  18518 18.2  2.2 111748 44624 pts/2    S+   04:05   0:00 [celeryd: celery@vagrant:MainProcess] -active- (-A python worker -c 1 -l debug)
vagrant  18522  0.0  1.9 104252 39020 pts/2    S+   04:05   0:00 [celeryd:celery@vagrant:PoolWorker-1]
```

Two workers:

```
celery -A python worker -c 2 -l debug
```

...

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ps aux | grep celery
vagrant  18525 19.2  2.2 111840 44732 pts/2    S+   04:07   0:00 [celeryd: celery@vagrant:MainProcess] -active- (-A python worker -c 2 -l debug)
vagrant  18530  0.0  1.9 104252 39020 pts/2    S+   04:07   0:00 [celeryd: celery@vagrant:PoolWorker-1]
vagrant  18531  0.0  1.9 104252 39080 pts/2    S+   04:07   0:00 [celeryd: celery@vagrant:PoolWorker-2]
```